# Centralized error handling

Tags: c#, exception

I went through few threads at Stack-overflow, I am bit confused about the words about centralized error handling.

1. One Article in codeproject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43182/Centralised-Exception-Handling-in-C-Windows-Applic), explains handling it in the main method through threads
2. In MSDN, they mentioned like "Use try/finally blocks around code that can potentially generate an exception and centralize your catch statements in one location. In this way, the try statement generates the exception, the finally statement closes or deallocates resources, and the catch statement handles the exception from a central location"

Could any body clarify more about centralized error handling and what is the best way to implement it?

Comment: The 1 and 2 you listed make sense and to me they are quire clear. What in particular do you find confusing? Otherwise your question seems too broad to me.

Comment: Check out [Centralized Exception Handling](http://codebender.denniland.com/centralized-exception-handling/)

Comment: @Mokchhya, I went through that too "Handling exceptions in a method which executes a code block", Seem there are lot of alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only part of error handling that might be centralized would be the logging of the error.

- only handle those exceptions that your program may be able to apply some control over
  ( restart for a timeout exception for example)
- finally blocks should be used to release unmanaged resources, note that finally blocks run after either the try block or exception block run

Comment: ...finally should be strategic - don't try to close an assumed open db connection here if the original exception was generated by trying to open it in the first place.